# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que haya una verficación, si un una casilla tiene "-" después de cada número?

Tags: javascript

¿cómo puedo hacer la verificación a una casilla, que debe tener un guion de separación de cada vez que se copie un número?

Ejemplo

```
1-2-6-2 ó 10-5-11
```

Se que se hace con las Expresiones regulares, pero no se como.

Comment: para tu suerte mozilla tiene un web donde podras aprender a utilizar expresiones regulares https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp saludos!

Comment: ¿Algo que hayas intentado?¿Cómo obtenés esos números?

Comment: Puedes utilizar esta pagina [regexr](https://regexr.com/) para que hagas pruebas y cuando tengas alguna dificultad no los cuentas, mas lo que has intentado.

Comment: ¿En una casilla?

Comment: si  class="form-group" id="arepi">
                 <label for="gradoR">Cuales </label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="gradoR" name="gradoR" placeholder="Ejem: 1-9">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible solución.

```js
    const numbers = '1-2-3-4'

    function ensureNumbers(str, delimiter) {
         const regex = new RegExp(/^\d+$/)
         return str.split(`${delimiter}`).every(e => regex.test(e))
    }

    console.log(ensureNumbers(numbers, '-'))
```

```
// Usando funciones flecha
const ensureNumbers = (str, delimiter) => str.split(`${delimiter}`).every(e => /^\d+$/.test(e))
```

Al separar la string mediante el delimitador que tú digas y convertirlo a un array, podrás comprobar que cada elemento sea un dígito y si alguno no lo es, te devolverá false. Si el elemento del array no es un dígito es porque en esa posición del array se ha colado algo y no se ha separado correctamente por lo que no es únicamente un número.